# Equation labeling when an array is used inside an equation

Tags: equations, labels, arrays

I was wondering why the below equation labeling is not working when I have an array environment inside an equation environment. I realized that when I remove `[fleqn]` from `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`, the labeling works. Why?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:array}
    V_{koietc} = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        & \lambda \times \sum_{\substack{i^{'} \in \{1,2,\dots,i\} \\ t^{'} = (i-1) \times FR_k + t - 1}}
        \hspace{0.5cm} \forall e < E_k; t \in \mathcal{T}; c \in \mathcal{C} \nonumber \\
        & \lambda \times \sum_{\substack{i^{'} \in \{1,2,\dots,i\} \\ t^{'} = (i-1) \times FR_k + t - 1}}
        \hspace{1cm} \forall e = E_k; t \in \mathcal{T}; c \in \mathcal{C} 
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

print \eqref{eq:array}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: `i^{'}` is wrong; it should be either `i^{\prime}` or, more simply, `i'`. Ditto for `t^{'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you switch to a `dcases` environment, which is provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package. With this switch in place, the placement of an equation number seems to experience no problems, despite the `fleqn` option being in effect.

For the following screenshot, I inserted `[???]` in two places as they don't seem to indicate what the terms of the summation actually are.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for dcases env. and \mathclap macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:array}
V_{\mathrm{koietc}} = 
    \begin{dcases}
    \qquad\lambda \times \sum_{
       \mathclap{\substack{i' \in \{1,2,\dots,i\} \\ 
                 t' = (i-1) \times \mathit{FR}_{k + t - 1}}}}
       \mbox{[???]}
       &\quad\forall e < E_k, t\in\mathcal{T}, c\in\mathcal{C}  \\[\jot]
    \qquad\lambda \times \sum_{
       \mathclap{\substack{i' \in \{1,2,\dots,i\} \\ 
                 t' = (i-1) \times \mathit{FR}_{k + t - 1}}}}
       \mbox{[???]}
       &\quad\forall e = E_k, t\in\mathcal{T}, c\in\mathcal{C} 
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
Print \eqref{eq:array}.
\end{document}
```